# error: object Stemmer is not a member of package org.apache.spark.mllib.feature

Tags: scala, apache-spark, text, stemming, mining

Importing the package org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Stemmer in Spark-shell using Scala returns the following error: 
:47: error: object Stemmer is not a member of package org.apache.spark.mllib.feature
       import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Stemmer

I am trying to use stemming to my words using:

```
val stemmer_product_title = new Stemmer()
  .setInputCol("ngrams")
  .setOutputCol("stemmed")
  .setLanguage("English")
```

Here ngrams is a 1-gram transformed text. Could anyone help me with this please? I would be grateful.

Comment: Could you provide your version of Spark MLLib ?

Comment: I am using spark 2.2.0 and scala 2.11.8

Comment: could anyone help me with this? I am a complete beginner in spark

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.master</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-stemming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or to your `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.master" %% "spark-stemming" % "0.2.1"
```